# Installing Printer from Local Network

Tags: 13.04, printing, hp

My problem is really simple.

I have a printer in my local network "HP LaserJet P4015" and I would like to connect to it but I don't know how.

Could someone please guide me how can I add a new printer in ubuntu "13.04"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into System Settings, and click on printers, and just follow the images below:

[image]

Click on Add, and then Printer

[image]

Click the little arrow to the left of Network Printer, and then choose the one that you have.

[image]

Comment: I see, I didn't have the "Printers" app under "System Settings" which is weird. But I installed it and everything works now. thnxx ..

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know the IP address of the printer, use [Angry IP](http://angryip.org/download/#linux) (which worked best for me) or alternative software to detect the printers' IP address. Once you know the IP, follow the instructions in the answer above (by Mitch).